# Is there any way in Lion to have "Natural" scrolling for trackpad and "reverse" for mouse?

Tags: macos, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Macbook Pro with Lion: scrolling via trackpad vs. mouse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22220/macbook-pro-with-lion-scrolling-via-trackpad-vs-mouse)

In Lion is there any way to have "Natural" scrolling for trackpad and "reverse" for mouse? They seem tied together in the system preferences. If I change one it changes the other. I would like UP on the mousewheel to scroll up but up on the trackpad to scroll down? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: also see question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22220/macbook-pro-with-lion-scrolling-via-trackpad-vs-mouse

Answer (score 4):

You may try [Scroll Reverser](http://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/). That screenshot says it all; you can invert scrolling per-axis and per-device, individually for trackpad and mouse.

[image]

([source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22220/macbook-pro-with-lion-scrolling-via-trackpad-vs-mouse))

Answer (score 2):

Use [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) -

With USB Overdrive, it is possible to alter any button on any input device like your mouse, and you can define specifics for a particular mouse or input device to suit your need.

All you need to do is to alter wheel up and wheel down for your mouse to be the opposite direction, so that wheel up is down and wheel down is up, and you can still retain the regular behavior for other devices.

Comment: This works fairly well, but I had to uninstall the logitech drivers to get it to work. Now my middle button doesn't launch "Mission Control" anymore. Can't find a setting in USB overdrive to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Though there are different settings, I have not had any luck with them being separate. When I set the mouse setting off it turns the trackpad setting off and when I turn the trackpad setting on it turns the mouse setting on.

This is with a logitech mouse without LCC installed, I haven't tried with an apple mouse though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) to reverse the buttons assigned to wheel up and wheel down, so that the mouse wheel gets swapped back.