# Disable "natural" scrolling on MacBook with High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, trackpad, macos

I've just updated my 2010 MBP to High Sierra, and I'm struggling to turn off the natural scroll feature for the touchpad (I prefer the old fashioned way).

Whenever I look in system preferences, there appears to be nothing relevant when I search for it:

[image]

If I try the Mouse or Trackpad sections, it just tells me that neither are connected:
[image]

I've also looked under the 'Mouse & Trackpad' section under 'Accessibility' and tried 'Mouse Options', but still no option for it.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181186/natural-scroll-direction-on-with-trackpad-off-with-mouse?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22220/macbook-pro-with-lion-scrolling-via-trackpad-vs-mouse?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences >  Trackpad > Scroll & Zoom [image]

Comment: If I try that, it tells me to connect a trackpad... it seems to be only capable of configuring an external trackpad rather than the one that is built in to the MBP

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of full system preferences app. I'm on mojave.